# Installing Node.js on browser server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building a multiplayer game with `node.js` and `socket.io` and uploading it to [itch.io](https://itch.io). I can install `node.js` on my windows computer but how do I install it on the server that I'm using? Thanks!

Comment: Did you know that first of all it's not called a browser server and that the operating system that your server is using plays a role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server that you would be using for deploying and running your app is just another machine(with OS) at a remote location- hence a remote server!

Now coming to your question- what you need to connect, install and run node.js on your server is a SSH client such as **Putty** (http://www.putty.org/).

You download and run putty on your windows machine and then enter your server's Hostname/IP-address. You will be able to see your server's terminal window once connected. Now you can go ahead and install node.js in it. Depending upon which operating system your server machine is running, you can install node.js accordingly.

Also, you probably want to transfer your project files that you created using node.js and Socket.io - for that you will need an FTP client such as FileZilla (https://filezilla-project.org/).

Once all that is done and your project is running- you can host it on your given website.

Comment: I'll try this and see if it works. I'll upvote it for now and accept it if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful start! I've asked another question on the topic if you want to look at it.